# Can work experience overcome bad undergrad grades for admissions to masters programs in Germany?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, grades, germany

I did my graduation in Electronics and Communication engineering, and now I am working as a software engineer for more than two years.

I have this problem that during my graduation I failed in a few subjects like analog electronics and organization behaviour. (Yeah!! It sucks that I kinda failed in Analog and Organization at the time, but now as I have experience working, I feel that they are very interesting and knowing there practical applications)

I cleared them in the following year, and passed my graduation all clear in the 4 year period.

I have three questions

1. Will I get into a high ranking German university?
2. Will the work experience count?
3. What else can I do to improve my profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to all your questions depends on the university. There are only some rough standards which needs to be implemented by the universities.

If you consider computer science at my university the state dictated that one has to have a *good* bachelor to enroll in the master courses. Now there are two possibilities: Either you have a grade better than 2.5 (which is a B- in the European grading system and considered barely *good*) or you have to give reasons why your bachelor is weaker and then a committee has to decide whether you are allowed to enroll. But I know that other universities and even other departments at my university have other rules.

Comment: The answer also depends on the field you want to specialize in. The top 10 place for theoretical cs may be different from the top 10 for software engineering and some of those might have a lower grade requirement than others and some might allow a motivation letter to compensate for half a grade (this is the perfect place for mentioning your work experience). Just find out which universities you're interested in and look at their admission requirements.